# How to share logo + immutable text with Facebook Opengraph for android?

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-share

I am integrating facebook SDK in my app, but I am a little confused by the sharing system.

My app is educationnal, and I'd like my user to be able to brag as "I had 100/100 on the test n°xx" and share it on facebook, just like you could do with Runtastic.

For those who wouldn't know it, here is what Runtastic shares look like (the example is in French but you get the idea) :

[image: runtastic shares example]

Since my app is not a game, this is not possible with Open Graph Stories (there is no type for educationnal), and Custom Open Graph Stories are now deprecated, so no object is relevant and I cannot create my own anymore.

**Knowing that, how can I make a ShareDialog that will look like this, with a big logo and a non-modifiable text beside, linking to a website ?**

The [Sharing documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android) tells everything about sharing a single thing but it is not really helpful when you want to combine it with text.

The closest thing to what I want would be to use `ShareLinkContent` with a link to my app on the playstore and a quote like. It do the trick, but it looks more like the user is just sharing a link (which is true), more than he is bragging about an achievement.

I could also share the logo as a photo and put the brag as a caption, but then the logo would ba too big and the caption has to be modifiable so everyone could tell he got 100/100.

NB : the text in french means "[this person] just terminated a run of 27.94 km in 3 hours and 6 minutes, saved with Runtastic app". I'd like my app to show "[this person] just got 100/120 on 2016 session, saved with MyAppName app".

NB2 : I haven't got any server, just a playstore link, a facebook app and a facebook page

Comment: Well, I use SharePhoto to create an object of this type, from a bitmap and then add the photo on OpenGraphObject using .PutPhoto() function along side with other things like title / description like this .putString("og:title", myTitle) & .putString("og:description", myDescription) Hope this will help you. I have kind of the same problem, but for me I can't change the verbose (works only for "reading a book"..idk why)

Comment: Could you put the whole code in an answer ? This sounds really good but I'm not sure which object I should create (since I thought you need an action to use an OpenGraphObject)

Comment: Yea, let me get to work and I will post you my code.

Answer (score 0):

There you go...

This is my function which will make an object with a title & description, also with a picture from a remote URL (but you will need to create a bitmap of that picture, for that I am using **Glide**

```
private static void shareFacebook(Context context, Bitmap picture, String title, String videoURL, String description) {
    SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
            .setBitmap(picture)
            .setCaption(context.getResources().getString(R.string.floh_site))
            .setUserGenerated(true)
            .build();

    ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
            .putString("og:type", "books.book")
            .putString("og:url", videoURL)
            .putString("og:title", title)
            .putString("og:description", description)
            .putPhoto("og:image", photo)
            .putString("books:isbn", title)
            .build();

    ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
            .setActionType("books.wants_to_read")
            .putObject("book", object)
            .build();

    ShareOpenGraphContent c = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
            .setPreviewPropertyName("book")
            .setAction(action)
            .build();

    ShareDialog.show(FlohApp.getTopActivity(), c);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I feared, you have to specify a `og:type`. My app is educationnal, you can pass tests. I could find no type on the doc that would fit to educationnal...

Comment: So, you don't want to specify an action ? Or you don't want to specify an type to the object? Can you explain how you want the share to look like ?

Comment: As I told in the title of the post and in the example image : a logo beside an immutable text

Comment: Also, you can check how your object would look like using [debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)

And if it looks ok for you (based on your URL) you can use ShareLinkContent :) I can't think of something else(I had the same problem, and end up sharing a simple picture / or a video URL from youtube)